# Why the browser shows the information from append in javascript as text, not code?

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<div class="my-input"><p>Add your information</p></div>
```

I want to add more DIVs using append, but the browser shows me the text not the result of the code.

JavaScript:

```
let inputSkill = `<div class="my-input"><p>Add your information</p></div>`;
function addSkill(){
this.parentNode.append(inputSkill);
};
for( btnAddFor of addUserSkill){
    btnAddFor.addEventListener("click", addSkill);
};
```

Browser Result:

```
<div class="my-input"><p>Add your information</p></div>
```

Not

Add your information

Could you please let me know why this is not working?

The best solution will be to use insertBefore but I receive the error "insertBefore on Node: parameter 1 is not of type Node"

```
function addSkill(){
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(inputSkill, this.parentNode);
};
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you read the documentation? [`append`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/append), [`insertAdjacentHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: Thank you very much, insertAdjacentHTML is my solution! Sorry about the documentation, but I'm a beginner, noob level.